# Regarding git prune

Tags: git

Is the below command dangerous in any way ?

```
git remote prune origin --dry-run
```

I had a look here [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html), but could not arrive at any conclusion

Comment: Next time read the documentation on the official Git site: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote It is recently updated and nicely formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is **not**.

A dry-run is by definition a simple output operation, modifying nothing whatsoever.